# Преобразование массива в строку по формуле name=:mask в PHP

Tags: php, pdo, php7

День добрый, подскажите как красивее сделать код.

Дан массив $params вида 'title' => $value, 'content' => $value2

нужно преобразовать в строку вида: **title=:title,content=:content** для подставления в PDO запрос.

Я сделал вот так:

```
    foreach (array_keys($params) as $args)
        $colums .= "$args=:$args, "; 
    $colums = rtrim($colums, ', ');
```

rtrim делаю для удаления ', ' с конца получившейся строки. Но чувствую что как-то громоздко для такой операции, есть более быстрое/элегантное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = implode(',', array_map(function($v){ 
                           return "$v = :$v"; 
                       },
                       array_keys($params))
                 );
```

либо с циклом, но в любом случае с implode будет лучше, чем самому объединять

```
$data = [];
//foreach($params as $k => $v) $data[] = "$k = :$k";
foreach(array_keys($params) as $k)  $data[] = "$k=:$k";
$result = implode(',', $data);
```

в общем ваш вариант не громоздкий, другие будут не меньше размером.

Comment: благодарю, с implode и вправду изящнее ;)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$result = array_reduce(array_keys($params), function($c, $i) {
    return (!$c ? '' : $c . ",") ."$i=:$i";
});
```